# communication with rpc service using indy HTTP client and Superobject DELPHI http 400 error code

Tags: delphi, http, superobject

Ok im stumped the following code gives me a http 400 error which tells me there is something wrong with the submitted data but i cant figure out what!:(

the client is set to encode URL (Ive tried both true/false);

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

    var
    O:Isuperobject;
    T:Tstringlist;
    begin
        T := Tstringlist.Create;
        O := SO('{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "method": getinfo, "params": "[]" }');
        t.Add(o.AsString)    ;
        idhttp1.Request.ContentType := '"application/json"';
        memo1.lines.Add(    idhttp1.post('http://127.0.0.1:8332/', T ) )


       end;

    end.
```

Maybe im to Tired who knows but this is driving off the wall :\

Documentation on the RPC client
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29

USES:

Superobject Link : http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6

Answer (score 1):

400 means "Bad Request". You are sending data that the server cannot process.  Try sending your JSON data using `TIdHTTP.Post(TStream)` instead of `TIdHTTP.Post(TStrings)`.  The TStrings version encodes the string data in a way that will likely alter the JSON data so it is not valid JSON anymore.  That version of Post() is meant for 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' requests instead.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  O: Isuperobject;
  Strm: TStringStream;
begin
  O := SO('{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "method": getinfo, "params": "[]" }');
  Strm := TStringStream.Create(O.AsString);
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Post('http://127.0.0.1:8332/', Strm));
  finally
    Strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: still get the 400 Error but you enlightened me, i should have known that. im going to try it in a Tstream as a Json object also now.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

> Basic access authentication must be
>   used when communicating with it, and,
>   for security, by default, the server
>   only accepts connections from other
>   processes on the same machine.

So your code needs to set the Username, Password and BasicAuthentication properties of the Indy Request Object.

(A missing authentication normally causes a HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) instead of a 400.)

Comment: I forgot to add i set the Usr/pass in the property editor already!